# I want to get from which domain the request comes with its parameter in node js or express js

Tags: node.js, express, backend, nodejs-server

I only get the from which domain the request comes but I want to get the domain name with query parameters.
For example the main domain name with query parameters htpps://abc.com?userId=1&campaiginId=2

From above domain I request to https://external.com

`<img src="https://external.com"></img>`

Now from which domain request comes with query parameters I want like below this:

htpps://abc.com?userId=1&campaiginId=2

If I use req.get('origin') I only get the domain name but I need with query parameters too.

Thanks

// Here is my code

`req.get('/route', function (req, res) { var origin = req.get('origin'); console.log(origin) });`

// Now from which domain request comes with query parameters I want like below this:

// htpps://abc.com?userId=1&campaiginId=2

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL with its query params

```
const origin = req.headers.host;
console.log("Origin: ", origin)
const restUrl = req.originalUrl;
console.log("Rest part of the URL: ", restUrl);
```

Hope this help

Comment: can you share what exactly the difference between req.headers.host and req.get('origin')?